# Rails nesting routes inside one another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

If I were to have for example a 'languages' model view and controller. Then within that I were to have tracks, and then within that I were to have lessons. How would I go about making a route for the lesson, would it be:

`/languages/:language_id/tracks/:track_id/lessons/:lesson_id`

Doing this would mean nesting them, something which is advised against.

My question is how would I create a route that would suit this and still convey to Rails the parent and it's identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right. You shouldn't nest your route no more than 1 level deep. However to get the approach you are after by using shallow nesting as highlighted here: [Section 3.7.4](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=7). Primary purpose for this is to generate the collection actions scoped under the parent, so as to get a sense of the hierarchy. So you could do:

```
resources :languages, shallow: true do  
  resources :tracks do 
    resources :lessons
  end 
end
```